# Restarting Ubuntu causes grub to open

Tags: reboot

I have Ubuntu 14 LTS updated. After updating, I need to restart/reboot, I did it and it was shown the grub2 menu. I choose Ubuntu. But I don't really know if Ubutu succeded in restarting Ubuntu because I suspected grub2 may be preventing Ubuntu from restarting. It's just a ignorant doubt, please don't downvote me, if you think the question is fair to close, please answer but at least give me a positive answer if this is the correct procedure for restarting the Ubuntu.

Comment: I was expecting Ubuntu to load automatically without passing trought Grub, because Restarting Ubuntu seems ethimologycally "Shutting Ubuntu down and power ubuntu on". I want to know if my ubuntu was fully restarted or not. If you feel this question should get closed please consider I really need this help! At least keep it open for a week!

Comment: Don't be afraid of GRUB.

Answer (score 1):

GRUB is the bootloader. It comes up before any OSes have booted, because it is what allows them to load. If it shows up, your computer has rebooted.

There's no way GRUB loads without the computer having shut down, as it is the BIOS that makes GRUB start.

Comment: But Grub also comes afterturn off and power on, wich isn't the same as rebooting. Your answer clarifies me that at least the pc is being shut down but I heard that reboot is more extreme that shut down because it resets the kernel. I am off? Thanks!